# Difference between Content Search Web part and Search Result Web part

Tags: content-search-web-part, display-template

I know that Content Search web parts(CSWP) is available only on Enterprise edition. And other [great features](http://en.share-gate.com/blog/sharepoint-2013-content-search-webpart) as compared to Search Result web part (SRWP).

When would it be preferable to use either of them? (In terms of Search Scope)
Also, how easy/difficult is it to create display templates using SRWP ([reference](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/95131/add-display-template-for-search-result-web-part))

Answer (score 1):

The main difference is that the **CSWP** (Content Search Web Part) has the possibility that the power user is actually going to be able to choose which property he wants to place in your template, while the **Search Results Web Part** doesn't.

https://en.share-gate.com/blog/sharepoint-2013-content-search-webpart

Answer (score -2):

Please refer these articles, *Difference between Search Result web part and Content by Search web part* :

- [Part I: AvailableSortsJson property](http://prashamsabadra.blogspot.com/2014/03/difference-between-search-result-web.html)
- [Part II: TrimDuplicates property](http://prashamsabadra.blogspot.com/2014/03/difference-between-search-result-web_6.html)
- [Part III: Result Types](http://prashamsabadra.blogspot.com/2014/07/difference-between-search-result-web.html)
- [Part IV: Priority of the content](http://prashamsabadra.blogspot.com/2015/01/difference-between-search-result-and.html)

Comment: Please do not post link-only answers, try to include the important part in your post and then use the links as sources only

Answer (score -4):

Please refer these articles:

- [SharePoint 2013 Content Search WebPart and Search Results](http://en.share-gate.com/blog/sharepoint-2013-content-search-webpart)
- [Content Search Web Part vs. Search Results Web Part](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/sharepoint/en-US/ce14dfac-e44e-431a-8384-4cc213c7547c/content-search-web-part-vs-search-results-web-part)

Comment: Please do not post link-only answers, try to include the important part in your post and then use the links as sources only